# Power BI date condition

Tags: date, if-statement, powerbi, dax

I have two date fields
"MonthEndDate" and "date" I want a condition to satisfy that if date is less than 15 then take previous month end date and if date is more than 15 then take current month end date. Eg-

| MonthEndDate | date | ResultDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6/30/1999 | 7/2/1999 | 6/30/1999 |
| 10/31/1999 | 11/1/1999 | 10/31/1999 |
| 5/31/2009 | 5/28/2009 | 5/31/2009 |

Comment: what if I want to have 12 Trailing months and 3 trailing monthend dates from "ResultDate"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using power query

```
 let
        Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Ashok\Power BI\Stack Overflow\data_08_nov_21.xlsx"), null, true),
        Data_Sheet = Source{[Item="Data",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
        #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Data_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
        #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"MonthEndDate ", type date}, {" date ", type date}}),
        #"Inserted Day" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Day", each Date.Day([#" date "]), Int64.Type),
        #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Day", "Custom", each if[Day] < 15 
    
    then Date.EndOfMonth( Date.AddMonths([#" date "], -1))
    else Date.EndOfMonth([#" date "])),
        #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom",{{"Custom", "ResultDate"}})
    in
        #"Renamed Columns"
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ashok, what if I want to have 12 Trailing months and 3 trailing monthend dates from "ResultDate"?                MonthEndDate date ResultDate
6/30/1999 7/2/1999 6/30/1999
10/31/1999 11/1/1999 10/31/1999
5/31/2009 5/28/2009 5/31/2009